# Creating AlertDialog with Static Methods?

Tags: android, static, android-activity, surfaceview, android-alertdialog

I've completed most of the game I'm attempting to make and throughout the project I've created one particular Activity which also calls a SurfaceView and a Thread.  I put an update() method in each of the 3 classes so they each know where the other ones are everytime something changes.  Apparently, the only way to do something like this is using static methods... This is fine until a collision occurs in my SurfaceView and I want to tell the Activity what to do. I can relay the information, but then I cannot find a way to make an AlertDialog.

I understand I cannot call showDialog() from a Static method, but I cannot find a way to make a non-static method to call it with and then call that method from a static one.  I've been searching for an answer and I've heard something about instantiating the object but I cannot figure out what that means...

If anyone has a good idea to get me around this, please let me know :)

Comment: I think to remember that static dialog are discouraged because they are linked to a Context, which can become quite an issue when the Activity is destroy ( screen rotation for instance. )

Comment: Why don't you pass the context to your static method?

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Sephy, I have read alot that static methods are a bad idea in the long run, and I avoided the problem as much as I could, but it seems I cannot find a way around this one.  I know I have to call a method in the Activity from the SurfaceView, which forces me to use a static method... Right?

Pentium10, I'm sorry but this is my first game ever, I kinda understand what a context is but I'm unsure what you mean, can you point me to an example or anything? I'm not so concerned with fixing the problem as I am understanding what's wrong... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I used:

```
public static void messageDialog(Activity a, String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(a);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    dialog.create().show();     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceView extends View and thus have a getContext() method

To create and show your AlertDialog, you can do the following code inside your SurfaceView

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle("title");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
Dialog d = builder.create();
d.show();
```

This might not work as Activity.showDialog(int) if your activity is restarted (the dialog might simply disappear and you will have to handle state yourself).

Hope this helps

Comment: You can't call getContext() in a static method.